# How to apply dist_google (from stplanr package) to a list of data frames?

Tags: r, lapply

I am a beginner user of stplanr package. I have splitted a large data frame with long/lat points per 25 rows because dist_google function can be applied up to 25 pairs of origin - destination. So here is the original large data frame:

```
   GPSLatitude GPSLongitude
1     40.66126     22.89565
2     40.66127     22.89565
3     40.66128     22.89565
4     40.66130     22.89566
5     40.66131     22.89567
6     40.66132     22.89569
7     40.66134     22.89573
8     40.66136     22.89577
9     40.66137     22.89582
10    40.66141     22.89594
11    40.66142     22.89601
12    40.66145     22.89609
13    40.66147     22.89618
14    40.66150     22.89627
15    40.66152     22.89635
16    40.66155     22.89644
17    40.66160     22.89650
18    40.66165     22.89654
19    40.66172     22.89656
20    40.66178     22.89658
21    40.66186     22.89659
22    40.66193     22.89660
23    40.66200     22.89662
24    40.66207     22.89663
25    40.66213     22.89664
26    40.66218     22.89665
27    40.66223     22.89665
28    40.66227     22.89664
29    40.66230     22.89663
30    40.66234     22.89662
31    40.66238     22.89661
32    40.66242     22.89662
33    40.66244     22.89664
34    40.66245     22.89666
35    40.66247     22.89669
36    40.66248     22.89671
37    40.66249     22.89673
38    40.66250     22.89674
39    40.66251     22.89676
40    40.66253     22.89679
41    40.66255     22.89683
42    40.66257     22.89686
43    40.66261     22.89694
44    40.66263     22.89698
45    40.66265     22.89700
46    40.66267     22.89702
47    40.66268     22.89705
48    40.66270     22.89707
49    40.66272     22.89709
50    40.66273     22.89710
51    40.66274     22.89711
52    40.66275     22.89712
53    40.66275     22.89714
54    40.66276     22.89716
55    40.66276     22.89718
56    40.66276     22.89721
57    40.66275     22.89725
58    40.66273     22.89728
```

Then, I splitted this data frame per 25 rows with the following command:

```
pointssplit<- split(pointsdf, (0:nrow(pointsdf))%/%25)
```

Finally, I have the following list of the smaller data frames:

```
List of 3
 $ 0:'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ GPSLatitude : num [1:25] 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 ...
  ..$ GPSLongitude: num [1:25] 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 ...
 $ 1:'data.frame':  25 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ GPSLatitude : num [1:25] 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 ...
  ..$ GPSLongitude: num [1:25] 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 ...
 $ 2:'data.frame':  8 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ GPSLatitude : num [1:8] 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 40.7 ...
  ..$ GPSLongitude: num [1:8] 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 22.9 ...
```

I've tried to use lapply to apply the dist_google() function:

```
lapply(length(pointssplit), dist_google(from = point2, to = pointssplit, mode = "driving", google_api = "my api key")) #point2 is my reference point
```

The problem is that I don't know how to manage with "to" inside dist_google() in order to get the long/lat from each data frame separatelly so I get an `Error in match.fun(FUN)`
Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Comment: As it is already a split, you can do `lapply(pointssplit, function(dat) Map(dist_google, from = dat$GPSLatitude, to =  dat$GPSLongitude, mode = "driving", google_api = "my api key")) )`

Comment: @akrun I tried running the command but I had an error:  Error in `[.data.frame`(x, 2) : undefined columns selected

Comment: sorry, I haven't tested it as there is a apikey and other stuff